# Minimal entropy with constraint on $2$-norm: Finding reference

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory

Suppose $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n \in [0,1]$ and they satisfies
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n p_j = 1 $$
and
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n p_j^2 = C $$
with a given constant $C \in [1/n,1]$. The problem is to find the minimum of 
$$ -\sum_{j=1}^n p_j \log p_j .$$
Obviously, this problem could be solved by method of Lagrange multipliers. Since I believe that this problem is pretty typical, I have a question:

> Is there any literature (paper or book) which solved this problem?

Comment: It should not be so different from maximum entropy distributions: 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution

The minimum gets abritrarily close to 0 as $C \to 1$.

Comment: Note that you are trying to minimize a concave function, i.e, maximizing a convex functoin. This is difficult in general; your feasible set is also not convex but you can get around that issue.